# Expanding jsob array in PostgreSQL to produce analytics

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Imagine that we have the following table using `jsonb` on PostgreSQL:

```
create table writer
(
  "firstName" varchar,
  "surName"   varchar,
  books       jsonb
);
```

And the following data is available:

```
INSERT INTO public.writer ("firstName", "surName", books) VALUES ('William', 'Shakespeare', '[{"name": "Hamlet"}, {"name": "Romeo and Juliet"}]');
INSERT INTO public.writer ("firstName", "surName", books) VALUES ('Agatha', 'Christie', '[{"name": "Hercule Poirot"}, {"name": "Miss Marple"}]');
```

Is it possible to expand the JSON array to 2 columns similarly to what PowerBI expand does and get the following result?

| firstName | surName | bookName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| William | Shakespeare | Hamlet |
| William | Shakespeare | Juliet |
| Agatha | Christie | Hercule Poirot |
| Agatha | Christie | Miss Marple |

instead of

| firstName | surName | books |
| --- | --- | --- |
| William | Shakespeare | [{"name": "Hamlet"}, {"name": "Romeo and Juliet"}] |
| Agatha | Christie | [{"name": "Hercule Poirot"}, {"name": "Miss Marple"}] |

Sample DB: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87ca94/2

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` to get one row per array element:

```
select w."firstName", w."surName", b.book ->> 'name' as book_name
from writer w
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(books) as b(book)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fc2554a600b54df95f0f0522e52d1169)

Comment: Everything works as expected if you do not have null values. What happens if you have null values?

Comment: Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3b8de9/1

Comment: @glarkou: then use an outer join: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c5be040d7d916c56f2a89bdda7e39ea